# lost memo app. data

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I was unable to use my password protection on this app. I foolishly stopped and cleared.data under the apps setting thinking it would allow me to access my needed memo. Is there a way to get the memo data back as I seemed to have cleared everything?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you do not have a backup of your data, no.

Some apps do sync their data with Google Cloud Data services. I am not sure if this app does this as I don't know what app you are talking about specifically. From the looks of it, I would say it doesn't.

You may want to look at something like [Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=en) for future use. It will keep memos and such, and the data is sync'd with google services, so clearing the data out you should still be able to access the memos. And you can access from multiple platforms.